# .SHELLSTATUS empty when echo in make recipe

Tags: shell, if-statement, makefile

I'm trying to error in a Makefile based on the the exitcode of a python script. The catch is that I still want the print output of that script, even if it is either succesfull and failed.
In short I need to replace a hashed password which is returned by the python script into a yaml config file.
I got the following, but I am unable to parse .SHELLSTATUS into the if statement.
I'm using version GNU Make 4.3

The Makefile

```
HASHED_SECRET = $(shell python3 $(DIR)/src/generate_secret.py $(PASSWORD))

_config:
    $(info $(HASHED_SECRET))
    $(info $(.SHELLSTATUS))
    @if [ "$$.SHELLSTATUS" != 0 ]; then \
        echo "error: $$HASHED_SECRET; exit 1;\
    fi
```

And generate_secret.py

```
"""Return hash of the key, used for prometheus web-portal access configuration"""

import sys
try:
    import bcrypt
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1)
# pylint: disable=line-too-long

args = sys.argv

if len(args) == 2:
    try:
        PASSWORD = str(args[1])
        hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(PASSWORD.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt())
        print(hashed_password.decode())
        sys.exit(0)
    except BaseExceptionas e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)

else:
    print('not enough arguments given')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unable to parse .SHELLSTATUS into the if statement.

This ...

> ```
>     @if [ "$$.SHELLSTATUS" != 0 ]; then \
> ```

... instructs the shell to test the value of a *shell* variable named `.SHELLSTATUS`.  What you want to access is a *make* variable by that name (which isn't even valid as a shell variable name, on account of the `.` in it).  You may use either `${.SHELLSTATUS}` or `$(.SHELLSTATUS)` to do that, but I prefer the latter syntax because it is harder to confuse that with a shell variable access.  The same applies to `make` variable `HASHED_SECRET`.

Overall, then:

```
_config:
    $(info $(HASHED_SECRET))
    $(info $(.SHELLSTATUS))
    @if [ "$(.SHELLSTATUS)" != 0 ]; then \
        echo 'error: $(HASHED_SECRET)'; exit 1;\
    fi
```

Note also that I have both inserted the missing quotation mark and converted from double quotes to apostrophes for `HASHED_SECRET`.  That will not interfere with `make` expanding the value, and it is safer (but not *completely* safe) because the shell will not recognize any special characters within, except only another apostrophe.

Comment: More fundamentally, `.SHELLSTATUS` is unlikely to contain the exit code of the `$(shell ...)` invocation if your Makefile is at all more complex than this example. Probably a better approach would be to run the Python script within the recipe itself.

Comment: This is the only complex part of the whole Makefile. Rest of the file is some more easier substitutions and docker-compose setup.
How do you see the python script in the recipe? My experience is that it didn't change anything to the result. But to be fair I kept to to the ```.SHELSTATUS``` method.